# UWP VisualTreeHelper Wrong Parameter Reference

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, visualtreehelper

I want to modify the content in a `TabItem` of a `TabView`. And that `TabItem` uses `DataTemplate`.

When I am trying to access the children of that item like the following:

```
        var container = tabview.ContainerFromIndex(tabview.SelectedIndex);
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container);
```

I got the `ArgumentException: Wrong Parameter Reference` on the second line. How should I use VisualTreeHelper to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a easy method:

```cs
public static T GetChildObject<T>(DependencyObject obj, string name) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    DependencyObject child = null;
    T grandChild = null;

    for (int i = 0; i <= VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) - 1; i++)
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

        if (child is T && (((T)child).Name == name | string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
        {
            return (T)child;
        }
        else
        {
            grandChild = GetChildObject<T>(child, name);
        }
        if (grandChild != null)
        {
            return grandChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

From your description, you can already get the container of the target element. Let's assume that the element you need is named `TargetEle` and the type is `TextBlock`. You can write it like this:

```cs
var target = GetChildObject<TextBlock>(container,"TargetEle");
```

**Update**

I tested your code and found that you didn't capture the events loaded by the page.

In fact, the `SelectionChanged` event is fired when the TabView is just created, but the visual tree is not loaded yet, and you can't get the content from it through the code. You can create an `IsLoaded` property in the page, set it to True when Page Loaded, and determine this property in the `SelectionChanged` time.

Only when it is True, proceed to the next step.

Comment: I cannot do this `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj)`. It gives me an exception described in the question.

Comment: Can you describe how you created `TabView`(include XAML code)? Check the Container you get. Is it the expected value?

Comment: It is expected. I don't think how it is created matters as I am adding new functionalities to my app. If you really want to see it, it's [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/PlaylistsPage.xaml).

Comment: Ah, the `ContainerFromIndex` is null. Although the `SelectedIndex` is expected.

Comment: I tested your code and found that you didn't capture the events loaded by the page. In fact, the `SelectionChanged` event is fired when the TabView is just created, but the visual tree is not loaded yet, and you can't get the content from it through the code. You can create an `IsLoaded` property in the page, set it to True when Page Loaded, and determine this property in the `SelectionChanged` time. Only when it is True, proceed to the next step.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am doing wrong! Please modify your previous answer because that was not the answer I expect but your comment really is.

Comment: If possible can you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830417/uwp-get-children-from-templated-tabviewitem)?

Comment: I will simply say that your `PlaylistControl` is not a child of the `TabViewItem`, which is misleading. You can find your `PlaylistControl` at the TabView level using the recursion method I provided in the answer. Of course, you need named `PlaylistControl`. VisualTreeHelper is not recommended, it is easy to get the code deadlocked.